# Unable to get multiple connection to MySql on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, tomcat, windows-7

I have installed MySql on windows 7 ... issue is i'm unable to get multiple connection to MySql .

If I connect to MySql through command line and at the same time open an other MySql command line client it goes into wait state, as soon as I disconnect the first one later one gets connected.

Because of above issues I'm unable to run tomcat in debug mode as it tries to get more than one connection to MySql in debug mode.

Previously I was using same version of MySql i.e. 5.1 on vista and it was working fine.

when connected with only one MySql Command line "show processlist" results

`|  4 | root | localhost:49487 | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist`

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

and after connnecting with 2nd command line which hangs "show processlist" on the 1st window results

`|  4 | root | localhost:49487 | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist`

|  5 | root | localhost:49518 | NULL | Sleep   |    0 | NULL  | NULL

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

I entered following command through command line.

`mysql -u root -h localhost -P 3306 -p`

it asked me for password and got connected. Then I opened an other command prompt entered the same command it asked for password and hanged. I went back to the previous command line and closed it and the current one got connected. **max_connection** is 100 in **my.ini** file and **show processlist** reutns same result as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many re installation of Windows I guess i have identified  the root cause ... On every fresh installation MySql use to work fine but after a while I use to get stuck with this issue.

The cause was my voip messenger "Wizton" after installing it MySql work fine but when i restart my machine ... same Connection issue.

But wizton was working perfectly fine with Vista Business .. don't no what happens in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

What is your 'max_connections' setting (`show variables like '%max_connections%'`) and how many connections are currently 'live' on the server (`show processlist`)?

I'm guessing it's set very low (1 or 2) and between tomcat and your monitor connections you're exceeding the limit.

Raising it would be done via the mysql.ini/mysql.cnf file, wherever it's kept on Windows.

Comment: Hi Marc, max_connections is set to 100 and there is only one process running.

Its not just tomcat, any mysql client that tries to connect to MySql goes into wait state unless I disconnect the 1st one.

I have checked it by starting the MySql service again, disabling the firewall but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting over the network? or a local file socket? You may be locking on the windows equivalent of mysql.sock - not sure if that behavior changed in Win7. Something like:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p 3306
```

and make sure that my.ini/my.cnf have networking enabled

Comment: Everything is on my laptop i.e. local machine .. can you suggest how can I verify locking ? ... as you see "show processlist" show one connection is sleep state there is no lock state.

Comment: Edited with an example - this is using the commandline, though I apologize, I don't have a Windows box in front of me.

Comment: I have edited my question with result of the command you specified. Please check and thanks a lot for helping.